# class properties are not available in generic method c#

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

I am calling a generic method with two different classes as below:

```
FillDataPointsInOrder<Metrics>(dataPoints.Where(O => O.SortOrder != null).OrderBy(O => O.SortOrder));
FillDataPointsInOrder<Metric>(angieStatsCmp.GetDataColumns());


private void FillDataPointsInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataPoints)
{
    foreach (T dpoint in dataPoints)
    {
        if (!dpoint.IsPhone)
            FillDrp(this.EmailDrp, dpoint.Name, dpoint.MetricId.ToString(), dpoint.VName);

        if (dpoint.IsPhone && this.IsPhoneShop)
            FillDrp(this.PhoneDrp, dpoint.Name, dpoint.MetricId.ToString(), dpoint.VName);
    }
}
```

in "FillDataPointsInOrder" method I am getting compile errors :

```
'T' does not contain a definition for 'IsPhone' and no extension method 'IsPhone' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Same errors for Name , MetricId  and VName properties.
Not sure why T is not able to access properties of Metrics and Metric.
If I remove the code from generic method and write it directly in foreach over dataPoints it is working fine.

Can somebody advise what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FillDataPointsInOrder` only knows it will be called with a `T`. `T` could actually be string, int or anything.

If you want to call properties on T, you will have to use a `where` constraint.

But in this case it looks like your method does not even need to be generic.
If both `Metric` and `Metrics` share a base class or an interface that has the properties you need:

```
interface IMetric {
  bool IsPhone {get; }
}
```

you could just have:

```
private void FillDataPointsInOrder(IEnumerable<IMetric> dataPoints)
```

Note that IEnumerable is covariant, so if `Metric` is a `IMetric`, `IENumerable<Metric>` is a `IEnumerable<IMetric>`

Comment: Good point. In the example given in the question there's no apparent need for a generic method in the first place if the relevant interface or base class exists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to at least tell the compiler something about T if you want to do that. Do you have an interface that has members like IsPhone, Name, MetricId, etc. that your classes implement?

If so you can add a 'where' constraint to your class definition:

```
public class Something<T> where T : ISomethingElse
```

...where ISomethingElse is the interface that implements IsPhone.